# How to Filter .netCore thrown validations on Front-end side

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, validation

I have been developing A front-end project with Angular.
Back-End side has been develeoped with netCore.

On back-end Side Validation Rules results returning  with throw method Like this;

And I only need validation rules string in it to show them on the Page.

I Mean,I have no chance to change Back-End that's why have to filter it. Only need this

Name: Name can not be null
Address: Addrees con not bu null Severity
Address:  Addres must be at least 3 charecter Severity

Is it possible to Fİlter it?

FluentValidation.ValidationException: Validation failed:
-- Name: Name can not be null: Error
-- Address: Addrees con not bu null Severity: Error
-- Address:  Addres must be at least 3 charecter Severity: Error
at Core.Validations.FluentValidation.ValidationTool.Validate(Object entity, IValidator validator) in C:\Users\atakan.gunay\source\repos\EReconcilationBackendProject\Core\Validations\FluentValidation\ValidationTool.cs:line 23
at Core.Aspect.Validation.ValidationAspect.Before(IInvocation invocation) in C:\Users\atakan.gunay\source\repos\EReconcilationBackendProject\Core\Aspect\Validation\ValidationAspect.cs:line 40
at Core.Utilities.interceptors.methodInterceptors.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) in C:\Users\atakan.gunay\source\repos\EReconcilationBackendProject\Core\Utilities\interceptors\methodInterceptors.cs:line 21
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
at Castle.Proxies.ICurrencyAccountServiceProxy.Add(CurrencyAccoundAddDto currencyAccoundAddDto)
at EReconcilationUI.Controllers.CurrencyAccountController.Add(CurrencyAccoundAddDto currencyAccoundAddDto) in C:\Users\atakan.gunay\source\repos\EReconcilationBackendProject\EReconcilationUI\Controllers\CurrencyAccountController.cs:line 53
at lambda_method724(Closure , Object , Object[] )
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()

Comment: use httpintercepter in frontend

Comment: I already use httpintercepter . I just cannot Fİlter the message. there is no object on the response body that I can parse.

Answer (score 0):

Try error.message()

//or

```
let validationError = JSON.parse(err.text());
for (var fieldName in validationError) {
     if (validationError.hasOwnProperty(fieldName)) {
       this.error.push(validationError[fieldName]);
     }
}
```

Comment: that is impossible. Because the returned errror mesage Just a string. everything you can see above is just a string value. Cannot parse liket that.